# Scoring pandas column's vs other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to rank how many of other cols in df is greater than or equal to a reference col. Given testdf:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'RefCol': [10, 20, 30, 40], 
                      'Col1': [11, 19, 29, 40], 
                      'Col2': [12, 21, 28, 39], 
                      'Col3': [13, 22, 31, 38] 
                      })
```

I am using the helper function:

```
def sorter(row):
    sortedrow = row.sort_values()
    return sortedrow.index.get_loc('RefCol')
```

as:

```
testdf['Score'] = testdf.apply(sorter, axis=1)
```

With actual data this method is very slow, how to speed it up? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to compare `RefCol` and check if there are any column less than the RefCol , use:

```
testdf.lt(testdf['RefCol'],axis=0).sum(1)
```

---

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    2
```

For greater than equal to use:

```
testdf.drop('RefCol',1).ge(testdf.RefCol,axis=0).sum(1)
```